# Got error when trying to submit order via rest api and stripe

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, stripe

I have magento 2 setup, with Stripe plugin, and I'm trying to create order using

PUT `http://ec2-3-236-104-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/order`
BODY

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "stripe_payments",
        "additional_data": {
            "number": "4242424242424242",
            "exp_month": "10",
            "exp_year": "30",
            "cvv": "123"
        }
    }
}
```

after that I get error response

```
TypeError: Return value of
Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Sales\OrderManagement\AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin::aroundPlace() must
implement interface Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface, null returned in
/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Plugin/Sales/OrderManagement/AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin.php:214
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Sales\OrderManagement\AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin->aroundPlace()
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Service/OrderService/Interceptor.php(32):
Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(566):
Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService\Interceptor->place()
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(456):
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit()
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callParent()
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement/Interceptor.php(23):
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(414):
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->submit()
#10 [internal function]: Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->placeOrder()
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95):
call_user_func_array()
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188):
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process()
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent()
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(23):
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#17 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116):
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch()
#18 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#19 /var/www/html/magento2/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#20 {main}
```

Logs from system.log

```
[2021-04-15 13:57:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-04-15 13:57:23] main.ERROR: Magento2 v2.5.7: You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method. [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that method aroundPlace, probably in this class: `Magento/InventorySales/Plugin/Sales/OrderManagement/AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin` and check its return.
It must return an interface `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`.

Comment: it seems not I checked logs, do you know what does it mean?

Comment: [2021-04-15 13:57:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-04-15 13:57:23] main.ERROR: Magento2 v2.5.7: You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method. [] []